# Add javascript file added as link to the BundleCollection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

There are two projects in my solution, the first one is the class library and the second is the MVC 4 project.

The first library contains the javascript file which `Build Action` is `Embedded Resource`.

I want to use this javascript file in my MVC project and would like to avoid copying it, that is why I added it as a link (visual studio's Add as link). Then I'm trying to add this file to the `BundleCollection`

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Content/Scripts/xxx")
       .Include("~/Content/Scripts/xxx.js"));
```

but the script is not referenced on the page after rendering it there.
I have tried to set the property "`copy to output directory`" of the linked file to "`Copy Always`" but it didn't work. Simply copying and adding the file to the MVC project works as expected, but I would really like to avoid having two copies of it.

Is there a way to add linked script to the `BundleCollection`

Answer (score 2):

My only suggestion is to copy the file as a post-build event. You can xcopy the file through a batch file.

Comment: Yep. Not really any other choice here. The problem is the bundler actually does its thing at runtime, once the application has already been deployed and is no longer within the safe confines of Visual Studio where links actually work.

Comment: +1 @ChrisPratt yes, I understand the difference between build- and runtime, but hoped for another ellegant idea. The problem is that the MVC project is dependent on the library and not vice versa, otherwise I could reference the file in MVC and embed it in the lib even as a link :)